# Sanitized input for subprocess with shell=True in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, openstack, popen

I have python script, which has code.

```
...
...
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell=True)
output, error = p.communicate()
...
...
```

When I run [`bandit`](https://github.com/openstack/bandit) it gives error.

```
>> Issue: [B602:subprocess_popen_with_shell_equals_true] subprocess call with shell=True identified, security issue.
   Severity: High   Confidence: High
   Location: mypackage/myfile.py:123
123                                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
124                                          shell=True)
125                     output, error = p.communicate()
```

Then I do some google, and found that, I have to sanitized my input and with [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) and [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) I can sanitize it.

I changed my code to.

```
...
...
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(shlex.quote(cmd)),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell=True)
output, error = p.communicate()
...
...
```

But still I get same error, is there any way to remove this error when run `bandit -r mypackage/myfile.py`

Comment: `bandit` cannot determine whether the command argument is sufficiently sanitized; it can only detect that you are using `Popen` in a way that *could* be a security issue. You are probably better off leaving `shell=False` and preparing `cmd` yourself in a way that can be used directly by `exec`.

Comment: An analyser can't tell if a command you're running is a command you *want* to run. Depending on what you are doing, sandboxing the intepreter (for example with [codejail](https://github.com/edx/codejail)) might be appropriate or necessary. This involves a combination of input sanitisation and tightly-controlled operating system permissions.

Comment: @chepner, `exec` means, `subprocess.exec` ?

Comment: `exec` meaning whatever underlying system call is actually used to execute the command. Using a list with `shell=False` is safer because nothing interprets the arguments; the strings are passed as-is.

Comment: whether or not it is safe to use `shell=True` depends on the source for `cmd` (do you use a user input to construct it?). It is pointless and wrong to call `shlex.quote()`, `shlex.split()` here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes, this code runs behind API, and what data send to API, this code will execute that. So, user enter command which he want to run.

Comment: @Lafada: How do you stop a malicious user from entering a command that damages, crashes or takes-over etc. the system?

Comment: The right fix is to figure out why you (think that you) need `shell=True`, and fix it. If you're truly allowing remote users to run any arbitrary shell command... well, that's a huge security hole, and it's entirely correct for it to be flagged as such. Messing around with `shlex` to munge content that originally came from a remote source isn't actually going to solve the problem, it just makes your Python interpreter do (and then undo) logic that would otherwise only be done by the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, If I remove `shell=True` then `bandit` not remove error, it set down error from `Severity: High   Confidence: High` to `Severity: Low   Confidence: High`, it change `Severity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, user enter command which he want to run

If the user already may run any command including `bash` then the `bandit` 's warning about `shell=True` is not applicable.

The warning would make sense if the user were allowed only to choose some parameters for a fixed command e.g.,  a search query for a `grep` command:

```
rc = call(['grep', '-e', query, path])
```

whatever user-specified `query` is; it won't make it to run some other command (only `grep` is run).

Compare it with `shell=True`:

```
rc = call("grep -e '%s' '%s'" % (query, path), shell=True) #XXX don't do it
```

A user could pass `query = "a' /dev/null; rm -rf '"` that would produce  `grep -e 'a' /dev/null; rm -rf '' 'path'` command.

`shell=True` allows a user to run an arbitrary command in this case even if it is not intended. It is called a shell injection.

You could call `pipes.quote(query)`, to avoid naive attacks but it may fail in the general case that is why `shell=True` should be avoided if the input is not from a trusted source.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I will try to figure out something to remove `shell=True` but after making `shell=False`, still `bandit` raise error for that. It change `Severity` level from `Hight` to `Low`, there is no way to remove this also ?

Comment: @Lafada 1- the point of my answer is that it is likely pointless to remove `shell=True` in your case—it won't make your code safer. 2- how to disable the bandit's warning is a valid but different question. You should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: here my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661695/remove-bandit-notify-for-paramiko-and-subprocess-popen :)